# Join Postgresql array to table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following tables

```sql
create table top100
(
    id  integer   not null,    
    top100ids integer[] not null
);

create table top100_data
(
    id  integer   not null,    
    data_string text not null
);
```

Rows in table `top100` look like:
`1, {1,2,3,4,5,6...100}`
Rows in table `top100_data` look like:
`1, 'string of text, up to 500 chars'`

I need to get the text values from table `top100_data` and join them with table `top100`.
So the result will be:
`1, {'text1','text2','text3',...'text100'}`

I am currenly doing this on application side by selecting from `top100`, then iterating over all array items and then selecting from `top100_data` and iterating again + transforming ids to their `_data` text values.
This can be very slow on large data sets.

Is is possible to get this same result with single SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `unnest()` and re-aggregate:

```
select t100.id, array_agg(t100d.data order by top100id)
from top100 t100 cross join
     unnest(top100ids) as top100id join
     top100_data t100d
     on t100d.id = top100id
group by t100.id;
```

Or if you want to keep the original ordering:

```
select t100.id, array_agg(t100d.data order by top100id.n)
from top100 t100 cross join
     unnest(top100ids) with ordinality as top100id(id, n) join
     top100_data t100d
     on t100d.id = top100id.id
group by t100.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `unnest` and `array_agg` function in PostgreSQL, your final sql could be like below:

```
with core as (
select
    id,
    unnest(top100ids) as top_id
from
    top100
)
select
    t1.id,
    array_agg(t1.data_string) as text_datas
from
    top100 t1
join
    core c on t1.id = c.top_id
```

The example of `unnest` as below:

```
postgres=# select * from my_test;
 id |   top_ids    
----+--------------
  1 | {1,2,3,4,5}
  2 | {6,7,8,9,10}
(2 rows)

postgres=# select id, unnest(top_ids) from my_test;
 id | unnest 
----+--------
  1 |      1
  1 |      2
  1 |      3
  1 |      4
  1 |      5
  2 |      6
  2 |      7
  2 |      8
  2 |      9
  2 |     10
(10 rows)
```

The example of `array_agg` as below:

```
postgres=# select * from my_test_1 ;
 id | content 
----+---------
  1 | a
  1 | b
  1 | c
  1 | d
  2 | x
  2 | y
(6 rows)

postgres=# select id,array_agg(content) from my_test_1 group by id;
 id | array_agg 
----+-----------
  1 | {a,b,c,d}
  2 | {x,y}
(2 rows)
```